# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning from MessageEmbed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm new to discord bots and don't understand too much, so perhaps I'm being stupid.
I tried to make a message embed, but I get the error `(node:15832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function`. I tried copying the example from the discord website and just using that, but it still gives this error!.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // deal with messages / commands

    // If the message is "how to embed"
    if (message.content === 'how to embed') {
        // We can create embeds using the MessageEmbed constructor
        // Read more about all that you can do with the constructor
        // over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageEmbed
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            // Set the title of the field
            .setTitle('A slick little embed')
            // Set the color of the embed
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            // Set the main content of the embed
            .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
        // Send the embed to the same channel as the message
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }

});
```

The error:

```
(node:15832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.setup (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:77:91)
    at new MessageEmbed (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:18:10)
    at embedLikes.map.e (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:164:40)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveData (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:164:31)
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\index.js:36:19)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\leinb\Documents\coding\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
(node:15832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:15832) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What version of node and discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Update your Node.JS to version 12.x which you can do [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).
This also stands in the [README.md](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/README.md) on their GitHub.

Comment: I've heard that warning twenty times and never thought to actually check my node.js version. I guess this was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: No Problem :) Thank you too!